# EF Inserts already existing item

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.1 Code first for a website that I working on. No I have a small problem that EF tries to insert an item that is already in database, and that is already loaded from the database thru EF.

So I can actually see that the Item exist in context, but for some reason it add's the club again and mark it as added to the context. Here is what I am doing.

I have 2 entities. Club and User there is a many-to many relation between this to entities. So a Club can have many users and a user can belongs to many clubs.

- So I load the club from the database thru EF.
- Then I create a new User and add the club to my property Clubs on the user class.
- I then try to save the user thru EF.

Here I get an exception about violating primary key for Club. So it tries to Insert the club into the database when all it should do is add the clubidentifier and the useridentifier to my Club_User relation tables, adn of course save the user...

Why does the context think that it's a new club that should be added, when in fact the club already exist in the context?

Here is the code regarding club and user

First I create the EntityContext and add it to HttpContext.Current.Item

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //-- Create an instance of EntityContext
    HttpContext.Current.Items[Constants.ENTITYCONTEXT] = new EntityContext();
}
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //-- Clean up the entitycontext
    var entityContext = HttpContext.Current.Items[Constants.ENTITYCONTEXT] as EntityContext;
    if (entityContext != null)
        entityContext.Dispose(); 
}
```

This is in my Repository base class, this get's the entityContext from HttpContext.

```
//-- EntityContext
private EntityContext CurrentContext
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Items[Constants.ENTITYCONTEXT] as EntityContext; }
}
```

Here I get the Club I am going to use.

```
private Domain.Model.Club LoadClubByIdentifier(Guid identifier)
{
    return this.CurrentContext.Clubs.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Identifier == identifier);
}
```

Here is some of the code in my controllerclass that creates the user.

```
Domain.Model.User user = Mapper.Map<Web.Content.Code.Models.User.CreatePlayer, Domain.Model.User>(model);
user.Identifier = new Guid().NewSequentialGuid();

//-- Get current club
user.Clubs.Add(base.CurrentClub);

//-- Get all teams and add them to user
foreach (string teamIdentifier in model.Team)
{
    Domain.Model.Team team = new Domain.Services.TeamServices().LoadByIdentifier(
        Domain.Helper.CryptationHelper.DecryptIdentifier(teamIdentifier));

    user.Teams.Add(new TeamUser() { Team = team, User = user, UserTeamRelation = UserTeamRelationEnum.Player });
}

//-- Create this user
new Domain.Services.UserServices().CreatePlayer(user);
```

Here is the code in my userServices, doesn't do much yet...

```
public void CreatePlayer(Domain.Model.User user)
{
    Password password = Password.GenerateRandomPassword();
    user.Password = password;

    //-- Save the user to storage
    _userRepository.SaveUser(user);
}
```

And here is the code in the userRepository that adds the new user.

```
//-- Methods
private void SaveUser(Domain.Model.User user)
{
    this.CurrentContext.Users.Add(user);
    this.CurrentContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Best regards
Magnus

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a repository pattern, then you have to detach the Club you are adding from the Club Repository and attach it to the User Repository.  If you don't do this, then EF will mark the club as an added entity to the context and try to save the information that you already have for the entity, which you more than likely will have the Primary Key defined, thus violating the Primary Key contraint.

Comment: Hi. I am not sure if I use the repository pattern. I have one EntityContext that I store in the HttpContext.Current.Item, so it should be the same EntityContext thru the whole request. So when I load the club and save the user it's the same Entitycontext object that I use.

Comment: Can you post the code from getting the club and user from the context all the way until you save the user.

Comment: Hi. I have to do it later I am not able to access the code right now. But if I remember correct (after reading about repository patten) I use this pattern, but I don't create a new context for every repository, but uses the own that is stored in the HttpContext.Current.Item that is set in Application_BeginRequest() and disposed in the Application_EndRequest().

Comment: Ahhh... Never mind, I found the problem. The club was add to the context in another application request. If I put the EntityContext in HttpContext.Current.Session it works. But that can't be good from a performance point of view, can it?

Comment: using a dependency resolver would create a better abstraction of your code.  this would allow you to do `public UserController(IUserRepository userRepo) { _userRepository = userRepo; }` and then `public void CreateUser(User user) { User existingUser = _userRepository.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id); }`